# Помогите отловить баг при отправке HTML письма функцией mail() PHP

Tags: php, html, email

Господа, мое почтение. Очень странный баг.

У меня два аккаунта на одном хостинге, отправляя письмо с одного баг есть, с другого нет.

Суть:

Имею файл `with_pdf_button.html`, который я отправляю по почте. В письме стоит заглушка на месте имени пользователя `'££££'`. В коде ниже показано, что функция `str_replace` принимает файл, заменяет заглушку на Имя.

```
<?php
$name        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['firstname']));
$email       = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
$to          = "$name <$email>";
$subject     = "Hello! It's Price ";
$message     = file_get_contents('../mail_parts/with_pdf_button.html');
$message     = str_replace('££££', $name, $message);
$headers     = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers     .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers     .= 'Realm' . "\r\n";
```

Далее, вызываем функцию и ожидаем письмо

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Проверяю на тестовом сервере, письмо приходит и все как и ожидается. Выгружаю на продакшн.. в письме добавляется восклицательный знак с пробелом `!`  Прикрепляю скрин:

[image: Почему то добавляется Восклицательный знак с пробелом]

Причем чем длиннее будет name тем ближе к левому краю сдвигается `!`

Кто знает, в чем может быть дело? Почему такое может происходить?

[файл HTML](https://render.bigchange.com.ua/php/mail_parts/with_pdf_button.html)

Comment: Всё описали, а сам with_pdf_button.html не показали. Явно там непечатный символ будет какой-то.

Comment: @void приложил файл в самый конец своего вопроса, помогите разобраться)